# Ambiguity of adverbials

Tags: ambiguity, adverbials

For this sentence:

> People in my group are willing to share what they learn not only at work but also off work.

I want *not only at work but also off work* to modify *learn* instead of *share*.

How to remove the ambiguity?

Comment: Two English-to-Chinese translation applications give different results.
Should the principle of proximity be used?

Comment: If you want to use a conjoined noun phrase with a modifier, it's going to be ambiguous; you can't escape it. If you want to be clear about what modifies what, avoid conjunctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean *not only* should apply to *what they learn at work*, not simply the verb *learn.*

> People in my group are willing to share not only what they
> learn at work but also what they learn outside of work.

Moving *not only* to just before the fused relative headed by *what* makes clear that the coordination is between *what they learn at work* and *what they learn outside of work*.

It is advisable to repeat *what they learn* so that there is no confusion as to which part of the sentence everything that follows *but* is in coordination with.